# I am retrieving items from a list and want only 4 to show on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am retrieving items from a list, which has 5 items, but I only want 4 to show and every time I add a new item I want the new item to show first and then the other 3 items to follow and the fifth item must not show.

I have tried .last(), hide() but none of them help me accomplish what I want

```
<div id="phishing" class="row">
<!--Injected content-->
</div>
```

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/cyberSecurity/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('phishingExamples')/items",
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var items = data.d.results;
            var phishing = $('#phishing');
            var phishingCards;
            for (var i = 0; i <4; i++) {
                phishingCards = '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-3">' +
                   '<div style="background-color: #004685; height: 340px; position: relative;" class="card backImg2 ">' +
                    '<div style="color: #fff;" class="card-body ">' + 
                    '<h5 style="color: #ffe01a;" class="card-title ">' + items[i].Title + '</h5>' +
                    '<p style="margin-bottom: -5px;" class="card-text ">' + items[i].Description + '</p>' +
                    '<div style="width: 100%;  margin: 0 auto; position: absolute; bottom: 0;right: 0" class="row "><a style=" background-color: #ffe01a!important;  color: black!important; border: none; width: 100%;" href= "'+ items[i].Image.Url +'"class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  target=_blank>More Info</a></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';                

                phishing.prepend(phishingCards);
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        }
    }); // End Service Icons  //End Service Icons
```

I expect to show only 4 items on the page even if there is more than 4 items. I also want the new item to show first.

I actually get the new items first when I changed the loop to items.length but I only want to show 4 items.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Tul.jpg)

Comment: When you retrieve a new item, does the list include all the previous items? Are they in order, so that the newest one is first or last?

Comment: What results are you actually getting?

Comment: @Barmar right now the new item does not get appended. When I change the loop to 
```
for (var i = 0; i <items.length; i++) 
```
the new gets appended first but all items on the list get appended as well.

Comment: @kenef right now I the new item does not get appended even though I add a new item to the list.

Comment: You said the AJAX returns 5 items. Is it always the 5 newest items? Is the newest one first or last?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the structure of your items array?

Comment: @Barmar When changing the loop to items.length the newest show first but with the loop being < 4 the newest don't show at all.

Comment: You're prepending them, so they show in the reverse order from the array. So the newest is last in the array.

Comment: @kenef I am not sure what you mean by the structure of items array.

Comment: @DigiDev nm it was kind of a pointless questions. After looking at your code more closely I can tell that your array is a numerically indexed array of objects. I'll take another crack at this and post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array has the newest item last, but you're skipping that because you only show the first 4 items. Instead of starting from 0, subtract 4 from the length, and make sure it's at least `0`.

```
let start = Math.max(0, items.length-4);
for (let i = start; i < items.length; i++) {
```

Comment: I tested that code and didn't work because if I have only 4 items in my list it will show only 3 and the idea is to show 4. Currently in my test code, I have 4 items and it only shows 4, if I add a 5 item the code will work correctly and the new item will be added as first.

Comment: I thought the question said there are always 5 items.

Comment: Maybe you should just reverse the array and then take the first 4 of that. And append them instead of prepending.

Comment: yes maybe the the way I put it was sort of misleading but the idea is that no matter how many items you have on the sharepoint list it should always display the latest 4 items; starting by the newest. When I use append the newest shows as number 4.

Comment: @Bermar  If you don't mind can you explain the code to me? I know it worked but don't understand it quite well.

Comment: If the array has 5 items, it subtracts 4, which is 1, so it processes items 1 through 4. If the array only has 4 items, it subtracts 4, so it processes 0 through 3. If the array has 3 itimes, 3-4 is -1, but `Math.max(0, -1)` is 0, so it processes 0 through 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here I changed prepend() to append()

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/cyberSecurity/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('phishingExamples')/items",
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var items = data.d.results;
            var phishing = $('#phishing');
            var phishingCards;
            for (var i = 0; i <4; i++) {
                phishingCards = '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-3">' +
                   '<div style="background-color: #004685; height: 340px; position: relative;" class="card backImg2 ">' +
                    '<div style="color: #fff;" class="card-body ">' + 
                    '<h5 style="color: #ffe01a;" class="card-title ">' + items[i].Title + '</h5>' +
                    '<p style="margin-bottom: -5px;" class="card-text ">' + items[i].Description + '</p>' +
                    '<div style="width: 100%;  margin: 0 auto; position: absolute; bottom: 0;right: 0" class="row "><a style=" background-color: #ffe01a!important;  color: black!important; border: none; width: 100%;" href= "'+ items[i].Image.Url +'"class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  target=_blank>More Info</a></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';                

                phishing.append(phishingCards);
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        }
    }); // End Service Icons  //End Service Icons
```

or this, where I changed your for loop to run in reverse order, while retaining prepend().

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/cyberSecurity/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('phishingExamples')/items",
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var items = data.d.results;
            var phishing = $('#phishing');
            var phishingCards;
            for (var i = 4; i < -1; i--) {
                phishingCards = '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-3">' +
                   '<div style="background-color: #004685; height: 340px; position: relative;" class="card backImg2 ">' +
                    '<div style="color: #fff;" class="card-body ">' + 
                    '<h5 style="color: #ffe01a;" class="card-title ">' + items[i].Title + '</h5>' +
                    '<p style="margin-bottom: -5px;" class="card-text ">' + items[i].Description + '</p>' +
                    '<div style="width: 100%;  margin: 0 auto; position: absolute; bottom: 0;right: 0" class="row "><a style=" background-color: #ffe01a!important;  color: black!important; border: none; width: 100%;" href= "'+ items[i].Image.Url +'"class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  target=_blank>More Info</a></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';                

                phishing.prepend(phishingCards);
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        }
    }); // End Service Icons  //End Service Icons
```

Either one of these should reverse the order of the items in your array as they are printed to the dom. This is assuming that your existing code correctly prints only 4 items, I didn't see where you specified that it was printing more than 4 items except where you set items.length as the conditional in the for loop, which I'm not doing in these examples.

Also, I don't know what the structure of your items array is, but if the objects in that array have a date or timestamp property, then you can sort the array by that property first before running your for loop,  that way you can be certain of the order of your items. However this answer is running on the assumption that you only have Title, Description and Image as object properties because thats all I can see in your code.

Let me know how this goes!

Comment: you are right I only have title, description and image. I will try it and let you know how it goes.
Thanks